# Measure number of times users connect with Twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-anywhere

I'm using a connect with twitter button on my site, no an OAuth, but I wanted a way to accurately judge how many people pressed connect. There is a way to have a custom connect with twitter button like [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#login-signup). so i was thinking the button might bring you to a url to record the visit and then redirect right back to the main page. I'm not sure how or even *if* this idea will even work. How would I go a bout doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as present on the twitter website a method like this one can enable custom signin

```
document.getElementById("signin-btn").onclick = function () {
      T.signIn();
    };
```

simply call a url from inside this method fto track the number of clicks to this button some thing like this.

```
document.getElementById("signin-btn").onclick = function () {
          T.signIn();
$.get("UR_LINK");
        };
```

now on the server side. because i dont know what tech ur r using psuedo code can be

```
On_Request()
{
clicked++;
saveTODataBaseClickedNumber(clicked);
}
```

Comment: plz dont forget to mark as ans if it helped.. wud help others too

Comment: is there a way to do it flat file? maybe php?

Comment: flat file?? i dont know what u mean by that.. and im nt a php developer.. i develop in asp.net MVC and asp.net

Comment: i'm sorry. without a database